# How to generate latitude, longitude info using Faker from Laravel seeder?

Tags: php, laravel, faker

I am trying to use [Faker](https://github.com/stympy/faker#fakeraddress) in a Laravel seeder.

Here is how my seeder class look like

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Faker\Factory as Faker;

class LatitudeLongitudeTestTableSeeder extends Seeder
{

    public function run()
    {
        $faker = new Faker;

        $myTable = 'LatitudeLongitudeTest';

        foreach (range(1,10) as $index) {
            DB::table($myTable)->insert([
                'Latitude' => $faker->Address->latitude,
                'Longitude' => $faker->Address->longitude,
                'name' => $faker->Address->street_name,
            ]);
        }

    }
}
```

but this is giving me the following error

> [ErrorException]  Undefined property: Faker\Factory::$Address

I also tried to access the longitude property like this `$faker->longitude` but that still did not work.

How can I access the longitude property in faker to generate data?

Answer (score 12):

You should add `latitute` and others as properties. So, try something like this:

```
$faker->latitude(-90, 90)
```

Or:

```
$faker->latitude()
```

Comment: I get this error 
 `[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
 Call to undefined method Faker\Factory::latitude()`  it seems that I need to pull a different faker library. this is what I have in my composer.json file under the require-dev section `"fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",`

Comment: @Jaylen, I've just tested it and it works. I've got same version as you are. Try to run `composer update`, maybe package wasn't installed correctly.

Comment: I just finished updating everything. but still get this error ` [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
 Call to undefined method Faker\Factory::latitude()`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the you have mixed up Faker's object and `static` reference. 
You should either use it with static reference like

```
Faker::Address.latitude
```

or if you wanna use it with object do like this

```
$faker = new Faker(); $faker->address()->latitude;
```